Generated enums with custom values are not deserialized properly
It seems that the enums with custom value generated using the openapi-generator for spring server are not working properly.
Simple example to reproduce a problem. 
Openapi spec:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Simple Example
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /v1/hello:
    get:
      operationId: getGreetings
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: name
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - in: query
          name: greet
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GreetEnum'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "Success greeting"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
components:
  schemas:
    GreetEnum:
      type: string
      enum:
        - mr
        - mrs

build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.11'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '7.9.0'
}

group = 'dev.alubenets'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

openApiGenerate {
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/src/api-spec/api.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$projectDir/build/generated")
    generatorName.set("spring")
    apiPackage.set("${group}.api")
    modelPackage.set("${group}.api.model")
    configOptions.set([
            documentationProvider : "none",
            useSpringBoot3        : "true",
            useSwaggerUI          : "false",
            interfaceOnly         : "true",
            skipDefaultInterface  : "true",
            serializableModel     : "true",
            openApiNullable       : "false",
            useEnumCaseInsensitive: "true"
    ])
    globalProperties.set([
            apis  : "",
            models: "",
    ])
}

tasks.register('apiConfigure', DefaultTask) {
    project.sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDir "build/generated/src/main/java"
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn('openApiGenerate', 'apiConfigure')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

@Controller class:
@RestController
public class V1Controller implements V1Api {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> getGreetings(String name, GreetEnum greet) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello " + greet.toString() + " " + name + "!");
    }
}

TestController class:
@WebMvcTest(controllers = V1Controller.class)
class V1ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void getGreetings() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
            .perform(
                get("/v1/hello")
                    .queryParam("name", "Alex")
                    .queryParam("greet", "mrs")
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

I have got the following exception:
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'dev.alubenets.api.model.GreetEnum'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam dev.alubenets.api.model.GreetEnum] for value [mrs]]

Generated enum:
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-11-11T14:25:24.928137300+03:00[Europe/Moscow]", comments = "Generator version: 7.9.0")
public enum GreetEnum {
  
  MR("mr"),
  
  MRS("mrs");

  private String value;

  GreetEnum(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static GreetEnum fromValue(String value) {
    for (GreetEnum b : GreetEnum.values()) {
      if (b.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
  }
}

Generated interface:
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-11-11T14:25:24.928137300+03:00[Europe/Moscow]", comments = "Generator version: 7.9.0")
@Validated
public interface V1Api {

    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/v1/hello",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    
    ResponseEntity<String> getGreetings(
        @NotNull  @Valid @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
         @Valid @RequestParam(value = "greet", required = false) GreetEnum greet
    );

}

So, I'm assuming that @JsonCreator should be used to create an instance of enum from String, but it's not even used while I'm using debug with breakpoints.

Your assumption is wrong. There is no JSON serialization involved here. Only converting a parameter to an object. Which uses a Converter, it doesn't use Jackson for serialization as there is no requestbody with JSON being sent.
